# Reducing the font size of the drop down in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have dropdown in my HTML Page which has width more than 250px.

I need to change the dropdown font size so that the width gets reduced.

I tried using the font tag like below:

```
<font size='6'>
    <select>
    <option></option>
    .
    .
    .
    </select>
</font>
```

The above code didn't work.

When I tried reducing the width by hardcoding the value as **width='50'** it hides the full text of all the dropdown which becomes hard to select an particular option.

Suggest a solution so that width gets reduced and all the options visible in the dropdown.

**Note:** it should be compatible in IE8

Comment: `<select style="font-size:6px">` use something like this.

Comment: Just want to add: **The `<font>` tag is deprecated in HTML5 and should not be used**. Use inline styles, external stylesheets instead. (Only use it in email templates as Outlook is a retarded bastard)

Comment: same answer posted by me but got downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the font size, just apply `font-size:XXpx;` css property:

```html
<select style="font-size:6px;">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
</select>
```

Or, if you want to put it in your stylesheet:

```css
select{
  font-size:6px;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just want to say that `size="6"` does indeed do that, but not if you use it in a `font` tag :)

Comment: @some lol, I missed that OP put it in the <font> tag :D gunna edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `font-size` Rule on your `select`-element

```
<select style="font-size: 6px">
    <option>ABC</option>
    <option>ABC</option>
    <option>ABC</option>
    <option>ABC</option>
</select>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfs51Lsd/)

Comment: Already posted; try check in advance so as not to post dupe answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS for that.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9ddaexpz/

HTML:

```
<select id="myDropdown">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
#myDropdown
{
    font-size: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Already posted; try check in advance so as not to post dupe answers?

Answer (score 0):

try this simple method
external style sheet method

```css
select{font-size:6px;}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
</select>
```

Inline style sheet method

```html
<select style="font-size:6px">
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

In select tag use the css style given below.

```
<select style="font-size:6px">
    <option></option>
    .
    .
    .
    </select>
```

Comment: Already posted; try check in advance so as not to post dupe answers?

Comment: No matter dear.Glad to see that ur problem is solved.. :) @nicael

Comment: Wut? What problem did I have?

Comment: :D @nicael you have style problem in css

Comment: @nicael this is the third answer that you have, quite rudely, said you have already answered. Just so you know, we get it thank you.

Comment: @M_G Sorry for possibly being a bit rude, I didn't want to. But I am reminding this everyone who posts dupe answers and not the first time already. How strange wouldn't it be, I don't see any point in having duplicate content.

Comment: @nicael Its stackover flow not a chat room.What happen if someone post dupe answer.Its good to share ideas may be you posting your answer difficult to understand as compared to another answer.

Comment: @nicael O its not gramatical class that you points out gramatical mistakes.

Comment: The official name is Stack Overflow. And yes, there is no need in dupe content, if your answer dupes some another answer, delete it. At least in this case, our answers are identical and both are quite clear.

Comment: @nicael No. i cant delete my answer please you delete your answer :D Our answers are identical we are not identical :p